# Managing multiple key-pairs vs Bastion Host

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to hardening the EC2 security. So I have many EC2 instances and many developers that need access to these EC2 instances.
Each developer will have their own key-pair (public/private) and add the public key on each EC2 instance.

I will create a bastion host too. For the bastion host, what is the best approach? Add all pub key of the developers? Or create just on key pair and distributed it for the developers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's definitely better to have separate keys from each of the developers, that way you have the ability to revoke single keys and the other developers can retain their access.

You can even have a Git repository with the developers public key, and use configuration management to sync the repo with the .authorized_keys file if you want to get creative.

On the bastion host itself, you can just generate a single keypair to use for controlling access to the internal hosts. Since you don't need to distribute this, you can rotate this key at regular intervals in a fairly straight forward process.

In the event of a developer leaving, you can revoke their access to the machines by removing their pubkey from the .authorized_key files and removing their IP from the Security Group if applicable. You can also at that point rotate the internal key pair, but it isn't inherently needed as their access should be sufficiently cutoff provided that the internal instances only allow ssh access through the bastion host. (Set in the Security Groups)

Comment: The question is about the bastion host too.

Comment: As in maintaining private/pub keys for each user on the bastion host to be able to connect to the instances in the VPC? I don't do that, I allow the users to log in to the bastion host and from there, when they ssh into the firewalled machines, it pulls from a common keypair on the bastion host. If you're worried about security in the event of a developer leaving, having access to the keypair doesn't allow you access to the firewalled instances if they can't connect through the bastion host. Which would be revoked immediately, then you can rotate the key on the firewalled instances if need be.

Comment: The question is: How the developers connect to the bastion server? Which key/pair they use? Did you add the developer's pub key to the bastion?
And in the EC2 instances? Doess they have all developer's pub keys?
I think it is simpler to add all developrs pub keys to bastion host, and use a single key-pair to each ec2 instance. What do u think? Sorry I re-read your answer and know its clear!

Comment: Yes, that is the preferable setup. Just note that you do not have to distribute the keypair that is used to connect to the internal instances.

Comment: So to revoke the access of a user you just remove the pub key from bastions server, rigth?

Comment: Exactly. It's also a good idea to rotate the keys used for the internal instances regularly, and since you don't have to distribute those, it's fairly straight forward.

Comment: Update your answer plz. It can help more users.

Comment: Mathew. I already add the private key using ssh-add on the bastion server, but only me can see it. If i connect with other dev machine on bastion server and run `ssh-add -L` i cant see the private key of the bastion server. Is there a way to put it to all users?

Comment: is there any way to add to this ".authorized_keys file" from the Amazon consol web portal? I added another key pair from the portal but it does not work and it does not show up in the description page of the AMI. and obviously i would not be able to ssh into server to edit that file.